# How to change defaul font family in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a working app but I want to change default font family at app level. How to accomplish that without changing font family in every text element?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Text component, name it ex. CustomText and give it font family as you like.

Comment: any other way to set in android ?

Comment: I am not sure, I did it like this above.

Comment: would i have to change anything or properties will be applied to custom text automatically?

Comment: You don't need to change anything, just instead of Text from React Native use your custom text.